# SparkSQL - Error in Schema

Tags: apache-spark-sql

**I was trying to `count` a column data named doctorid using `distinct` but it is throwing error. can anyone please help me? I will be thankful. The full code is given below.**

```
scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

scala> val hospitalDataText = sc.textFile("/Users/TheBhaskarDas/Desktop/services.csv")
hospitalDataText: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /Users/TheBhaskarDas/Desktop/services.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:32

scala> val header = hospitalDataText.first()
header: String = uhid,locationid,doctorid,billdate,servicename,servicequantity,starttime,endtime,servicetype,servicecategory,deptname

scala> val hospitalData = hospitalDataText.filter(a => a != header)
hospitalData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at <console>:36

scala> hospitalData.take(2).foreach(println)
32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical
32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical

scala> case class Services(uhid: String, locationid: String, doctorid:String, billdate: String, servicename: String,
     | servicequantity:String, starttime: String, endtime: String, servicetype: String, servicecategory:String,
     | deptname:String)
defined class Services

scala> val hData = hospitalData.map(_.split(",")).map(p =>
     | Services(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8),p(9),p(10)))
hData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Services] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:40

scala> val temp = hospitalData.map(_.split(","))
temp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:38

scala> temp.take(2).foreach(println)
[Ljava.lang.String;@31201bf6
[Ljava.lang.String;@4159113f

scala> val temp = hospitalData.map(a => a.split(","))
temp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:38

scala> val hData = temp.map(p =>  Services(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8),p(9),p(10)))
hData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Services] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:42

scala> hData.take(2).foreach(println)
Services(32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical)
Services(32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical)

scala> val hosService = hData.toDF()
hosService: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [uhid: string, locationid: string ... 9 more fields]

scala> hosService.take(3).foreach(println)
[32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical]
[32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical]
[213d66cb9aae532ff46ef88c95836881f6c712a5,10351,13632bf7c504bc5ce14caddd54d257987eddf0fe,31:44.0,PT/INR,1,,,Investigations,Investigative,Haematology]

scala> hosService.printSchema()
root
 |-- uhid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- locationid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- doctorid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- billdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- servicename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- servicequantity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- starttime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- endtime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- servicetype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- servicecategory: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deptname: string (nullable = true)


scala> hosService.select("doctorid").distinct.count
[Stage 5:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]17/08/20 23:16:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/20 23:16:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 7)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/20 23:16:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/20 23:16:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/20 23:16:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/08/20 23:16:47 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2430)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2429)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2429)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

scala>
```

> hData.foreach(println)

```
scala> hData.foreach(println)
Services(32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical)
Services(32d84f8b9c519383841dcffff2e4a2b4918b2e55,10601,b330486ffbc04026dccc925e6820420a660d6238,26:21.0,OP Consultation - Follow Up Visit,1,,,Consultation,Consultative,Medical)17/08/20 23:55:24 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 14)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/20 23:55:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/08/20 23:55:24 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times; aborting job

Services(4a8f6c2cede8405d49f9dcada27e9b6fbbea2c6f,10601,e3f521e8e6db7a8937e8ab1319ba8f7af17ca5b8,17:31.0,DRESSING GAUZE PACK   6X6 (5 IN I ),2,28:52.0,,CSSD,Allied Services,CSSD)
Services(4a8f6c2cede8405d49f9dcada27e9b6fbbea2c6f,10601,e3f521e8e6db7a8937e8ab1319ba8f7af17ca5b8,17:31.0,DRESSING GAUZE PACK   6X6 (5 IN I ),2,28:52.0,,CSSD,Allied Services,CSSD)
Services(41408e7710d29714753fc1f0a6414423a8e3233e,10371,b6cdb2bc17c4f589161fe7bb37a1a2bb0fe82f4f,45:00.0,IP Visit Charges,2,00:00.0,,Consultation,Consultative,Wards Others)
Services(4a8f6c2cede8405d49f9dcada27e9b6fbbea2c6f,10601,e3f521e8e6db7a8937e8ab1319ba8f7af17ca5b8,17:31.0,DRESSING GAUZE PACK   6X6 (5 IN I ),2,28:52.0,,CSSD,Allied Services,CSSD)
Services(213d66cb9aae532ff46ef88c95836881f6c712a5,10351,13632bf7c504bc5ce14caddd54d257987eddf0fe,31:44.0,PT/INR,1,,,Investigations,Investigative,Haematology)
17/08/20 23:55:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 16, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
17/08/20 23:55:25 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 15, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
17/08/20 23:55:25 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:42)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

scala>
```

**Finally, I got the problem! `starttime` and `endtime` has blank that's why I was getting the error.**
[image]

Comment: One of your data points is missing a comma most likely - what happens when you run `hData.foreach(println)`? Most likely you'll get the exception on that line. Then you just need to handle this bad data case.

Comment: @JustinPihony I have tried with this, please check my updated question's bottom portion

Comment: Yes, this only proves my point that the data is invalid. If the set is small enough as it seems, then you can see which line is the problem by adding a println in the `hospitalData.map(_.split(","))` Making the map more like `.map(x=>{println(x);x.split(",")})`

Comment: @JustinPihony Finally got it for which reason I was getting the error. Check my updated question's below. Two columns has blank I didn't notice that. It should be null or anything else. Thanks for your time.